# Filter based on user input - LiveData, Recycler, RoomView

Tags: sqlite, filter, android-room, android-livedata

I have an SQLite Database for my Android App. Database has a **table** for **properties** , and another table for the **repairs** at each property.

**Table repairs**  :

```
@Entity(tableName = "repairs",
        indices = {@Index(value = "repairID", unique = true), @Index("repairPropID")})

public class MYRepairs
{
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "repid")
    public int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "repairID")
    @NonNull
    public String repairID;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "repairPropID")
    public int repairPropID;
}
```

...

and then **RepairsDao.java**

```
 @Dao
    public interface MyRepairsDao
    {
        @Query("SELECT * FROM repairs WHERE repid = :repid LIMIT 1")
        MYRepairs findRepairById(String repid);


        @Query("SELECT * FROM repairs WHERE repairPropID = :repairPropID")
        MYRepairs findRepairByPropID(int repairPropID);


        @Query("SELECT * FROM repairs ORDER BY repairPropID ASC")
        LiveData<List<MYRepairs>> getAllRepairs();

 @Query("SELECT * FROM repairs WHERE repairPropID = :repairPropID")
    LiveData<List<MYRepairs>> getPropertyRepairs(int repairPropID);

    }
```

In the **ViewModel**:

```
   public class repairViewModel extends AndroidViewModel
    {
        private MyRepairsDao myRepairDao;
        private LiveData<List<MYRepairs>> repairLiveData;
        private LiveData<List<MYRepairs>> repairPropertyLiveData;
        private LiveData<String> filterLiveData = new MutableLiveData<String>();

        public repairViewModel(@NonNull Application application)
        {
            super(application);
            myRepairDao = DogwoodDatabase.getDatabase(application).repairDao();
            repairLiveData = myRepairDao.getAllRepairs();
            repairPropertyLiveData = myRepairDao.getPropertyRepairs(propertyID);
        }

        public LiveData<List<MYRepairs>> getAllRepairs()
        {
            return repairLiveData;
        }

        public LiveData<List<MYRepairs>> getPropertyRepairs(int propertyID) 
        { 
            return repairPropertyLiveData; 
        }
```

And in the **RecyclerView.Adapter**:

```
public class repairListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<repairListAdapter.RepairViewHolder>
{
@NonNull
        @Override
        public repairListAdapter.RepairViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            final View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.repaircontent, parent, false);
            return new repairListAdapter.RepairViewHolder(itemView);
        }
```

In the **repairFragment** - we only want to view the **repairs for a user selected property**. Property Code **propertyID**  is received by the **repairFragement**. It is known to the **initData**()

```
   public class repairFragment extends Fragment
    {

        private repairListAdapter repairListAdapter;
        private repairViewModel repairViewModel;

        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            propertyID = getArguments().getString("ARG_PROPNUM_ID");
            propNumID = Integer.parseInt(propertyID);
            initData();
        }



     private void initData()
        {
            Log.e ("INIT", "ID is " + propertyID);

            repairViewModel = new 
                   ViewModelProvider(this).get(repairViewModel.class);


repairViewModel.getPropertyRepairs(propertyID).observe(this, new Observer<List<MYRepairs>>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(@Nullable List<MYRepairs> MYRepairs)
                {
                    repairListAdapter.setMYRepairList(MYRepairs);
                }
            });

        }
```

This returns NO RECORDS. 
In an ideal world, my properties would have no repairs, but I do not live in that world!

I have scoured this board for help on filtering .

Can you help me with how to **filter** for only the repairs for a user selected property (propertyID).

Thanks, Rachael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you wanted to do is the following:

```
public LiveData<List<MYRepairs>> getPropertyRepairs() { 
    return repairPropertyLiveData; 
}
```

And

```
private MutableLiveData<String> selectedPropertyId = new MutableLiveData<>();

private final repairPropertyLiveData = Transformations.switchMap(selectedPropertyId, (id) -> {
    return myRepairDao.getPropertyRepairs(id);
});

public void updateSelectedProperty(String propertyId) {
    selectedPropertyId.setValue(propertyId);
}
```

This way, you don't end up with new subscriptions that were not properly invalidated in case you were to select a different property id later.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my! I figured it out.

In repairViewModel:

```
public LiveData<List<MYRepairs>> getPropertyRepairs(int propertyID)
    {

        repairPropertyLiveData = myRepairDao.getPropertyRepairs(propertyID);
        return repairPropertyLiveData;
    }
```

Comment: This isn't really what you want. You want to modify a MutableLiveData that converts the ID to the DAO query through a SwitchMap.